# Is it possible to attach the source of the Oracle ojdb driver

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I'm having an issue related to the ojdbc pool connection and I need to debug the ojdbc driver in order to obtain more information about the error. Does anyone know if it's possible to attach the source code of the driver using Java Attach Source plug-in? I've tried but the plug-in seems to never finish attaching the source...

Comment: It would be surprising if you could even find the source code, let alone 'attach' it.

Comment: oracle jdbc driver is not a open source product.

Comment: As I supposed. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mikesmithjr/ora-jdbc-source/blob/master/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.java